# Compressed textures become white in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

i am new to both android and OpenGL development
i try to do just a cube with a texture, but i need to make this texture compressed in ETC1 compression, i make a code like i found in the develop.android website but the code  run only on the emulator !

i test on two devices

1) Nexus mobile, in this device the cube is not appeared, i search the internet, i found that the original Android of this device was 2.1, and it was upgraded to 2.3, This is a reason make the device can draw the cub ?

2) Motorola Xoom Tablet, it is an Android 3.1 Device, the cube is appeared here but with white color, not the Uncompressed texture, it is supported CTE1 and there are no OPENGL Error !

the compressed texture is PNG 265 * 265 / and i put the compressed texture in the raw folder

the code is like the following

```
public class TextureCube {
private String TAG;
private Context context;
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer; // Buffer for vertex-array
private FloatBuffer texBuffer; // Buffer for texture-coords-array

private float[] vertices = { // Vertices for a face
-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // 0. left-bottom-front
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, // 1. right-bottom-front
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // 2. left-top-front
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f // 3. right-top-front
};
float[] texCoords = { // Texture coords for the above face
0.0f, 1.0f, // A. left-bottom
        1.0f, 1.0f, // B. right-bottom
        0.0f, 0.0f, // C. left-top
        1.0f, 0.0f // D. right-top
};
int[] textureIDs = new int[1]; // Array for 1 texture-ID

// Constructor - Set up the buffers
public TextureCube(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    TAG = "Sam Messages: " + this.getClass().getName();
    // Setup vertex-array buffer. Vertices in float. An float has 4 bytes
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()); // Use native byte order
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer(); // Convert from byte to float
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices); // Copy data into buffer
    vertexBuffer.position(0); // Rewind

    // Setup texture-coords-array buffer, in float. An float has 4 bytes
    ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texCoords.length * 4);
    tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    texBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();
    texBuffer.put(texCoords);
    texBuffer.position(0);
}

// Draw the shape
public void draw(GL10 gl) {


    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW); // Front face in counter-clockwise orientation
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE); // Enable cull face
    gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK); // Cull the back face (don't display)

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); // Enable texture-coords-array
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texBuffer); // Define texture-coords buffer

    // front
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    // left
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glRotatef(270.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    // back
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glRotatef(180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    // right
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glRotatef(90.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    // top
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glRotatef(270.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    // bottom
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glRotatef(90.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);   // Disable
                                                            // texture-coords-array
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
}

// Load an image into GL texture
public void loadTexture(GL10 gl) {

    Boolean loadCompressed = true;
    if (loadCompressed) {
        /****************************************************/
        /** LOAD A COMPRESSED TEXTURE IMAGE */
        /***********************************/
        Log.w(TAG, ": ETC1 texture support: " + ETC1Util.isETC1Supported());
        try {
              ETC1Util.loadTexture(GLES20 .GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0,
                      GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5,
                      context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pic3));

            Log.w(TAG, ": OpenGL Error -After LoadTexture()-:" + gl.glGetError());
            Log.w(TAG,"OpenGL Extensions: " + gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, ": Could not load texture: " + e);
        } finally {

                Log.w(TAG, ": OpenGL Error -In Final()-:" + gl.glGetError());
        }
    } else {
        /*****************************************************/
        /** LOAD A TEXTURE IMAGE */
        /************************/

        gl.glGenTextures(1, textureIDs, 0); // Generate texture-ID array
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[0]); // Bind to texture ID Set up texture filters
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        InputStream istream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.pic5);
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istream);
        } finally {
            try {
                istream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        // Build Texture from loaded bitmap for the currently-bind texture
        // ID
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        bitmap.recycle();
        /******************************************************/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fail to setup a texture name for the compressed texture loading, the two function calls

```
gl.glGenTextures(1, textureIDs, 0); // Generate texture-ID array
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[0]); // Bind to texture
```

do this, so place them at the beginning of the function.

A "white" texture usually indicates, that the texture is incomplete. This usually happens if you enable mipmaping but don't supply all required mipmap levels. In the above code you disable mipmaping for uncompressed textures:

```
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL10.GL_NEAREST);
gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL10.GL_LINEAR);
```

but leave things as they are, for compressed – try what happens if you put those two calls after the name generation, i.e. also before the `if(compressed)`:

```
public void loadTexture(GL10 gl) {

    gl.glGenTextures(1, textureIDs, 0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIDs[0]);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    Boolean loadCompressed = true;
    if (loadCompressed) {
        /****************************************************/
        /** LOAD A COMPRESSED TEXTURE IMAGE */
        /***********************************/
        Log.w(TAG, ": ETC1 texture support: " + ETC1Util.isETC1Supported());
        try {
              ETC1Util.loadTexture(GLES20 .GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0,
                      GLES20.GL_RGB, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5,
                      context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pic3));

            Log.w(TAG, ": OpenGL Error -After LoadTexture()-:" + gl.glGetError());
            Log.w(TAG,"OpenGL Extensions: " + gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_EXTENSIONS));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, ": Could not load texture: " + e);
        } finally {

                Log.w(TAG, ": OpenGL Error -In Final()-:" + gl.glGetError());
        }
    } else {
        /*****************************************************/
        /** LOAD A TEXTURE IMAGE */
        /************************/
        InputStream istream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.pic5);
        Bitmap bitmap;
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istream);
        } finally {
            try {
                istream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        // Build Texture from loaded bitmap for the currently-bind texture
        // ID
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        bitmap.recycle();
        /******************************************************/
    }
}
```

Comment: datenwolf, 
i don't know how can Thanks ya man

it is worked, but really i can't understand well what you mean, Can you help me and send me a good tutorials that i can begin with 

Thanks you

Comment: @Samy: This is just the basic pattern of OpenGL texture creation: Allocate texture name using `glGenTexture` bind texture name to target texturing unit using `glBindTexture` set texturing parameters (use mipmaping, filter types) etc. by `glTextureParameter`, setup texture environment (required for multitexturing) and finally load the actual texture data using directly `glTexImage2D` or some helper function that will call it in the end. In depth tutorials are the chapter on texturing in the OpenGL programming guide http://goo.gl/WU9Qz and the NeHe texturing tutorial http://goo.gl/pBjfz

Comment: Thanks alot for your quick help